# Do we have gender declension for pronoun "qualcuno"?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, gender

I couldn't find documented info about it, but apparently some ".it" Italian websites use it. Do we have gender declension for pronoun "qualcuno"; for example, here which one is correct:

> Non vedo nessuno! non c'e qualcuno stella nel cielo.

or this way:

> Non vedo nessuna! non c'e qualcuna stella nel cielo.

Comment: I meant "there is no sky in the sky", like the first moments of sunset. when still there is no star in the sky to be seen! and of course i meant that "e", the third person singular of verb "essere"! but i didn't have that accent on my keyboard special while i could copy and paste from somewhere, but i thought it's not that much big deal to not get distinguished by "e" with the meaning of "and".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither is correct. Besides the fact that it is *c'è*, not *c'e*, did you mean “there are no stars in the sky” or “there are some stars in the sky”?

In the former case, it is *Non c'è nessuna stella in cielo* (or the slightly more formal *Non c'è alcuna stella in cielo*); in the latter, *C'è qualche stella in cielo*.

To answer the rest of your question, *qualcuno* has indeed a masculine and a feminine (*qualcuna*) form, but it is just a pronoun; in modern Italian it is not affixed to a noun. So, say:

> C'è qualche stella? Sì, ce n'è qualcuna.

And, in most cases you use a capital letter after an exclamation mark.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, now I can distinguish the difference of "nessuno" and "qualcuno". Thus, as I got "nessuno" can be used either as pronoun or adjective while "qualcuno" is only pronoun.

Comment: That's perfectly right, @Armin, about the difference in the modern use of *nessuno* and *qualcuno*.

Comment: Unrelated, but it spawns from your answer @DaG: when do you have lowercase after an exclamation mark?

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia: Un esempio al volo, che cito dal *Nuovo manuale di stile* di Roberto Lesina: «Normalmente il punto esclamativo conclude il periodo ed è seguito da iniziale maiuscola. Se però è posto al termine di una frase inserita nel discorso, il testo successivo continua con la lettera minuscola: “Perbacco! potevi stare più attento”».